# How do I add one continuous material for a UV map of multiple objects?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, uv

I tried searching for a while and couldn't find an answer... I have been modelling an item made out of multiple objects, which I want to share the same exact continuous material. Is there any way to achieve this? More specifically, the item is made out of combined pieces, like a puzzle, which I would like to keep separate, while sharing the same continuous material. I am not very versed in this, so if it is too much of a hassle, I can combine everything into one object if I really have to.

Edit:

[image: the model]
[image: the model from a different angle]

Comment: You can unwrap several objects at once, I don't know if this is what you want to do? Maybe show some screenshots?

Comment: @moonboots I did that, but is there any way to do it while keeping adjacent faces from different objects together? Also, after that, when trying to add materials, it would always get added only to one face... I'm probably missing a step

Comment: maybe with an option like Unwrap > Project from View, but maybe show what your objects look like

Comment: @moonboots I edited the post to add a picture. I also added some more details to my previous comment, because I accidentally pressed Enter too early xd

Comment: So as I said a good way to do it would probably to unwrap several objects together with the Project from View option

Comment: @moonboots alright, I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: Or join all the objects, unwrap with the Smart UV Project mode, paint on the surfaces with the Draw brush (Stencil option), then separate?

Comment: @moonboots Oh that's something I hadn't thought of. Sounds like it could be pretty effective. Thanks ^^